# VS 2017, react, salsa, webpack

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, reactjs, webpack, jsx

I was playing with Visual Studio 2017, and tried the following:

- New empty Web Project
- using npm, get React, React DOM, their respective d.ts and office-ui-fabric-react
- [structure of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S6HB.jpg)
- In Hello.tsx I have the following [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE2iu.jpg) which just imports the PrimaryButton component from office-ui-fabric tries to use it.

It should be a pretty straight forward thing to do, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Any idea why I am getting that error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can edit your question to contain code using code {} tags.

Comment: I have a screenshot of the structure of the project and also one of the code, just click on the corresponding words. I choose this option cause you can also see the error in the screenshot